# "implementation restriction: nested class is not allowed in value class This restriction is planned to be removed in subsequent releases."

Tags: scala

Description of the method :

> Given a list of futures `fs`, returns the future holding the list of
>   values of all the futures from `fs`. The returned future is completed
>   only once all of the futures in `fs` have been completed. The values
>   in the list are in the same order as corresponding futures `fs`. If
>   any of the futures `fs` fails, the resulting future also fails.

This is what I did :

```
implicit class FutureCompanionOps[T](val f: Future.type) extends AnyVal {
    /***

    //Some others method

    ***/
    def all[T](fs: List[Future[T]]): Future[List[T]] = async {
      var fsVar = fs;
      val l = List()     
      while(fsVar.nonEmpty){
        await{fsVar.head} :: l
        fsVar = fsVar.tail
      }
      l
    }
}
```

But I get the following compilation error at this line `def all[T](fs: List[Future[T]]): Future[List[T]] = async {` :

> implementation restriction: nested class is not allowed in value class
>   This restriction is planned to be removed in subsequent releases.

Could someone explain me this error and show me a workaround ?

Comment: indeed the implementation is full of surprise to say the least !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This specific problem can be solved by moving that method outside the value class (FutureCompanionOps).

```
def allOutside[T](fs: List[Future[T]]): Future[List[T]] = async {
    var fsVar = fs;
    val l = Nil      
    while(fsVar.nonEmpty){
        await{fsVar.head} :: l
        fsVar = fsVar.tail
    }
    l.toList
}

implicit class FutureCompanionOps[T](val f: Future.type) extends AnyVal {
    /***

    //Some others method
***/
    def all[T](fs: List[Future[T]]): Future[List[T]] = allOutside(fs)
}
```

Even the [FAQ on the course page](https://class.coursera.org/reactive-001/wiki/view?page=assignment_3_faq) provides no further explanation on what is going on here, only that the feature is experimental. An async{} leads into a macro from where it becomes difficult to follow so ... probably somewhere along the line a nested class is created which is not allowed in value classes according to [this article](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

You are also advised to not use async{} and await{} at all as of now.

N.b. you're code will not work but I should not spoil the fun as the question was not about that

Comment: "You are also advised to not use async{} and await{} at all as of now." what do you mean by that ? In the language or in the course ?

Comment: @nicolas I think because async{} and await {} are syntatic sugar, and can be both implemented with Promises (which appears to be more stable for the compiler for the moment).

Answer (score 5):

From the FAQ:

The Scala Async feature is nearing its first release and is partly experimental.

As a workaround for using Scala Async in value classes, consider moving the async invocation outside of the value class using the following trick:

```
class FutureOps[T](f: Future[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def foo: Future[T] = fooImpl(f)
}

def fooImpl(f: Future[T]) = async {
  val x = await { f }
  throw new Exception
}
```

If that or other code juggling and refactoring does not solve the problem, consider using regular functional combinators like  `map`,   `flatMap`,   `continueWith`  and the rest of their friends.